# wx.FilePickerCtrl SetBackgroundColor of File/Path box instead of entire object

Tags: wxpython

I have a wxFilePickerCtrl & am trying to colour the filepath/text background e.g. when the filepath no longer exists.

```
tcf_entry = wx.FilePickerCtrl(myframe, message="Select File", wildcard="TCF files (*.tcf)|*.tcf|All files (*.*)|*.*", name="FilePicker_tcf")
tcf_entry.SetBackgroundColour("red")
```

My code makes the real background of the widget red, rather than the text/path box itself.
Is there a simple way to colour the background of the filepath box?

What I get:
[image]

What I would like:
[image]

Environment is Windows & Python 37 with wx 4.1.1

Comment: try getting `tcf_entry.GetChildren()` then apply the colour to all of them or just the one you can identify as the one you want. I'm on gtk which presents in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your hint @Rolf of Saxony
I have managed to achieve the behaviour I want with the following additions:

```
        tcf_entry = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, message="File", wildcard="TCF (*.tcf)|*.tcf|All files (*.*)|*.*")
    children = tcf_entry.GetChildren()
    for element in children:
        if element.GetName() == "text":
            element.SetBackgroundColour("red")
```

Comment: I found a simple 1 line approach to add this to my function.
I guess its not so "pythonic" as its not as easy to read as the full function but the following works fine:
{list(tcf_entry.GetChildren())[0].SetBackgroundColour("purple")}
This obviously assumes that the "TextCtrl" is always the first element returned by GetChildren.

As a final solution, I decided to create a small function called SetFilePickerBackground(object, colour) which is passed the object which uses my original "for element in children" code.
I hope this solution will be more future proof for changes to wx/python